# numpydoc conventions: method modifies class but returns nothing

Tags: python, numpy, docstring, numpydoc

Question about numpydoc docstring conventions:

I have a class that contains a number of methods that return nothing, but add an attribute to the class. For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
         self.a = a
         self.b = b
         return

    def a_mult(self, mult):
        """
        Multiplies `a` by `mult`.

        Parameters
        ----------
        mult : float
            Value to multiply `a` by.

        Returns
        -------
        None
        """
        self.product = a * mult
        return
```

In this clumsy example, `MyClass.a_mult` doesn't return anything, but adds an attribute to `MyClass`.

I've included a docstring for `MyClass.a_mult` following the [numpydoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt) style guide. The docstring states that the method returns None, but I can't see a standard way of documenting how the `MyClass.a_mult` method modifies the `MyClass` instance.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Generally, if it sets an attribute (`product`) on the class, I'd call the method `set_product`...

Comment: "I have a class that contains a number of methods that return nothing, but add an attribute to the class." - that's highly unusual and usually a bad design. It makes your API a highly stateful mess, and it messes with Python 3's split-table instance dict optimization.

Comment: I also agree with @user2357112 -- setters should be used very sparingly.  If a user wants to set the product attribute, they can usually just do `my_class.product = my_class.a * mult`

Comment: Thanks @mgilson - I'm still getting to grips with classes and how they should be used!
At present, I have a class that contains some data that needs to be processed in several sequential steps. The class has several functions which each perform an operation on the data, and store it in a new class attribute. The next function in the sequence then operates on the newly created attribute. Is there a better/more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Just looking at that description, it seems to me like the class may be unnecessary ... Just use functions which accept the data that they need and return the processed result.

Comment: The example above is minimal and purely illustrative... the actual data processing is pretty complex. I put it in a class because it offered a convenient 'container' to keep everything in one place, make sure the analysis steps happen in the correct sequence, and make it as simple as possible for non-python-users to learn. Maybe I'm using classes in the wrong way... but it seems to work well!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Anyway, there are things like `np.ndarray.setfield` that modify numpy objects. Take inspiration from there? Also, when you say "documenting how the `MyClass.a_mult` method modifies `MyClass`", you actually mean "... method modified the `MyClass` instance", right?

Comment: Yes - that's what I mean. Edited wording! I think I've found a way of doing what I want - I've taken the suggestions above, and am modifying my class structure to minimise creating new attributes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following the helpful suggestions of @mgilson and @user2357112, I realised my classes were poorly designed. I have altered the so all stages of data analysis are stored in a dict. Analysis functions now add elements to the dict, rather than adding new attributes to the class instance.

Thanks for the pointers.